# Wndows IDE port error

Tags: windows-7, drivers, disk-controller

I am getting the following error in Windows 7 log:

> Event 11, atapi: The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Ide\IdePort2.

How can I find out which controller and drive that corresponds to?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a CD/DVD drive.

Load device manager and open the DVD/CD-ROM drives node. Right click on the driver and choose disable. See if that solves it.